# Displaying confirmation message to user when clicking outside of section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have a webpage where there is a section (it's to create some content), and also a top bar and a sidebar with internal links (the top bar and sidebar are ng controllers)
I would like to display a confirmation message for the user if he leaves the page while creating the content, or if he clicks on any of the links in the top bar or the sidebar.
I know that for leaving the page to something external I can use:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
    return 'some text here';
});
```

But I haven't figured out how to make it also appear for the sidebar/topbar buttons.
Also, I don't want clicking on those buttons on other sections of the website display this message. It's only for this content creation flow section.

Thanks in advance to all the experts.

Comment: It should work for links. If you redirect by using js however you need to trigger it manualy. Could you show one of the buttons code?

Comment: Hi, thanks, I just edited my description to show that the top bar and side bar are ng controllers

Comment: Could you still show us the related code?!

Comment: @DaveGotman see my answer .

Comment: So the section I want to user to not leave by mistake is like this:
<form novalidate="" name="forms.form" class="ng-pristine ng-scope ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-date ng-valid-time ng-valid-maxlength">
***A bunch of divs here***
</form>

The sidebar looks like this:

<aside ng-if="loggedInFlag" ng-include="'app/views/partials/sidebar.html'" ng-controller="SidebarController" class="aside ng-scope">
**** some divs here, which contains <a> elements ****
</aside>

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can achieve so. check whether the form is empty or not on click of anywhere outside of the form. If the form is not Empty then show your message whatever you want.If the form is found non-empty restrict use action of navigation, and show a message. With flag `isFormEmpty` you can check user has left with the empty form.

```js
var isFormEmpty = true;
function checkIfFormNonEmpty(){
$(":input").each(function() {
   if($(this).val() !== "")
   isFormEmpty = false;
   console.log();
});
}


$(".myClass").on("click",function(){
    checkIfFormNonEmpty();
    if(!isFormEmpty){
      alert("U cant leave empty form.")
      return false;
    }else{
      alert('yes you can go anywhere after clicking me.');
    }
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" class="myClass" >click Me</a>
<form id="contentForm">

<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Nmae.">
<input type="Password" placeholder="Enter Password">
<button type="button"  class="myClass">Submit Form</button>
</form>
```